# How can i achieve the bootstrap styling effect for a simple select dropdown-Jquery/CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple dropdown that I want to stylize so that it would bring the boostrap effect.
However, I'm not keen on using the boostrap.css for this purpose.

Is there any way I achieve this:

[image]

by using jquery/css??

html:

```
 <select class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
    <option>This Account</option>
    <option>Other Account</option>
</select>
<input class="search" type="search">
        <span class="search-icon"></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try this plugin: [Bootstrap Select](http://jquery-plugins.net/bootstrap-select-custom-select-for-bootstrap).